# How do I get my base url to reference the actual root of the application after refresh?

Tags: angular, nginx, nrwl-nx

I have multiple angular applications that(home, app1, app2, app3, app4), if I don't set their `<base href="/app1/" />` accordingly, I get the following error:

`Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`

But if I set their base URL accordingly and if I refresh the page, it doesn't have a reference to its home(/). They think their home is `'/app1/'` etc.

Ideally, asking angular to route home would take the user to `/`.

```
- home: '/'
- app1: '/app1/
- app2: '/app2/
- app3: '/app3/
- app4: '/app4/
```